# Can you use the Android Trace class from multiple threads?

Tags: android, systrace

Are you able to use the Android `Trace` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace.html) from multiple threads and have it log time doing operations on each of those threads appropriately?

In particular, I have 2 threads that are each doing things and I'd like to visualize what each thread is doing at a given point in time using systrace. The docs for `Trace` only say that you should call `#endSection` from the same thread that called `#beginSection`, but it doesn't say whether multiple threads can be making their own calls to `beginSection` and `endSection` at the same time. Does anyone know if this is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe.  It writes a marker to the systrace device, which is shared across multiple processes and threads.

Comment: Thread info is apparently added in the kernel at the ftrace layer